# Extract an element's index from JSON object in react

Tags: reactjs, loops

I have a JSON object where I need to access the index of the elements inside. I have managed to access the first element `"EFG"` in the below code. My console log reads `index 0`

My question: How can I edit the code to access the index dynamically?
For example, I want to click on "EFG" and get its index of 0, ABC and get its index of 1, and so on.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Wrapper from "../../UI/Wrapper";

const List = () => {
  const [company, setCompany] = useState(
[
{
    "company": "EFG",
     details[...]
},
{
    "company": "ABC",
     details[...]
},
{
    "company": "HIJ",
     details[...]
}
]);

  const filterComp = () => {
    const newArr = company.findIndex((c) => c.company === "EFG");
    {
      console.log("index", newArr);
      return newArr;
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Wrapper>
        <h2>Customer List</h2>

        {company.map((r, i) => (
          <li key={i}>
            <a
              onClick={filterComp}
            >
              {r.company}
            </a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </Wrapper>
    </>
  );
};
export default List;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a index param to handler.

```js
const filterComp = (index) => {
  console.log("Clicked on index:", index)

};
```

Update the click handler to get the clicked index:

```html
{company.map((r, i) => (
<li key={i}>
  <a onClick={()=>{
          filterComp(i)
  }}>
              {r.company}
            </a>
</li>
))}
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/prakash-react-map-index-example-46gv4 - Working Example

Comment: Thank you! Can you please edit the answer and remove ‘const newArr function’ for others reading this question and then I will mark as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a curried function to close over the mapped index into callback scope:

```
const filterComp = index => () => {
  // use the index
  ...
};
```

and attach as `onClick={filterComp(index)}`. I don't recommend using an `anchor` tag (`<a />`), especially if you aren't actually trying to navigate anywhere. I also don't recommend using the array index as the React key either, you should strive to use intrinsic values of your data elements. (*Array indices will work if you are not mutating the array state (deletes, sorting, etc)*).

```
{company.map((r, index) => (
  <li key={r.company}>
    <div onClick={filterComp(index)}>
      {r.company}
    </div>
  </li>
))}
```

Comment: Good suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Drew I am going to link to separate component I just needed to get this first step down of accessing the index. I will change the key that was just the default for the time being